# Kong Request Transformer template value debugging

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin, konga

I need to extend the functionality of a current Request Tranformer en Kong. It currently has a [template value](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer-advanced/how-to/templates/) that parses certain captured values and overrides the uri of the request.
Something like this:

```
$((function() ... // do things with captured values // ...)())
```

It's been working fine for quite a while, but now we need to debug a border case. The issue, is that we can't reproduce the error localy. Here my question arises: **is there any way to log something inside the template value?** When I do `print()` the template fails, and an error is shown in the proxy logs. I tried just in case with `kong.log()`

Comment: Have you tried turning of the sandbox for Lua code? See https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/reference/configuration/#untrusted_lua there are a few more settings, right below.